# mongo_get_nonce failing?

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently trying to establish a valid connect.  Whee.

Already worked around the master/slave connection problem when connecting to a slave node in my replication set.

My authentication call is failing inexplicably.  I've tracked it down to line 1180 of mongo.c:

```
    if( mongo_simple_int_command( conn, db, "getnonce", 1, &from_db ) == MONGO_OK ) {
```

The mongo_simple_int_command to check the master/slave relation is working, when pointed at the "admin" dB.

I've tried to authenticate against "admin", "local", and a db I whipped up for testing purposes, "asdf".

No joy.

I'm utterly new to MongoDB (just started working with it today).  Is there an external way to check the logs?  IT hasn't granted me that level of access (yet, but it looks like I may need it).

Do I really need to authenticate in the first place?  What could cause "getnonce" to fail against an existing database?  I can understand if I queried "DBThatIsntThere", but this?  Weird.

--Frustrated

"Mongo have deep feelings for Sheriff Bart"

Comment: Are you using the C driver? If so, it's quite possible that there's a bug in the feature you're attempting to use.

Comment: Yes I am.  Sorry I didn't make that clearer.  My current theory is that I MUST connect with the replication set version of connect.  Still its quite odd that it fail in "getnonce".  Wildly unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called it.

When connecting to a replication set, you must use the c driver's `mongo_replset` `_init`, `_add_seed` and `_connect`, thusly:

```
mongo myMongo;

...

mongo_replset_init(myMongo, "setName");
mongo_replset_add_seed(myMongo, "someHost", somePort); // some number of seeds added.
mongo_replset_connect(myMongo);
```

I suspect this problem isn't limited to the C driver.